# Can a string of message be sent along a CAN bus?

Tags: string, hash, can-bus

I have generated the CAN message using the command `cangen -v slcan0`in SocketCAN and then I converted the generated CAN message into a hashed message using cryptographic Hash functions such as SHA-1, SHA-256, MD-5 etc.Is it possible to send this string of message(hashed message) along the CAN bus? or should the string be converted into binary form?.

But if I convert it to binary form it becomes a very huge number a CAN frame would accommodate only 8ytes or 64 bits similarly the hashed message cannot be sent as such in the CAN bus.

what are the other ways by which the hashed message can be sent along the CAN bus to the receiver side?

Attached a screenshot of hashed messages. Here `dev.recv()` receives the CAN message generated and then converts it to hash

[image]

Comment: No matter the format, you'll need some form of higher layer protocol to handle the payload and split it over several packages. Though, sending strings over CAN bus is weird... what is the actual problem you are trying to solve and why must you use CAN?

Comment: I am trying to secure the CAN messages send along the CAN bus for connected cars  by means of cryptographic techniques such as Hash, HMAC, MAC etc

Comment: I found two higher layer protocols that support CAN 1)can-isotp 2)CAN FD.I am using CANtact toolkit as my CAN device which does not support CAN FD.Comming to can-isotp ,it allows to send upto 4096 bytes but those bytes must be in CAN message format. So how can these hased message be sent along the CAN bus could you suggest any other higher level protocol which supports CAN?

Comment: CAN FD is not a higher layer protocol, it is a new physical/data link standard. You could look at the CANopen SDO protocol for inspiration, but if you don't have CANopen, then using that one as-is will be needlessly complicated.

Comment: You should be able to use ISO-TP.

This will segment your data into chunks, where each chunk fits into a CAN-message.
The receiver side will assemble the message again from the chunks.

Comment: Does ISO-TP accept strings like hash as input? It accepts data only in CAN message format like 123#80.68.A0.10.6A.80.56.AD.12.14.AB which is more than 8 bytes long

Comment: ISO-TP accepts data (same as CAN, by the way). It is just a transport protocol without any assumptions on the content. It just transports bytes, not caring whether it is a string, a number or anything else. The difference between ISO-TP and plain CAN is that the former allows to transport up to 4096, the latter only 8 bytes of data. The 36 bytes of string data to be sent in one ISO-TP message would be split into 6 CAN messages.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following solution:
Convert your data from ASCI to HEX
Then send the HEX data Using CAN ISOTP which gives you the possibility to send up  to 4095 bytes of payload per message packet, but you have to implement the protocol on both sides first

Comment: Latest version of ISOTP allows even bigger frame than 4095. The size stands on 32bits, so theoritically 4GB of data